# Yup is throw error when I have min and not required

Tags: typescript, yup

I try to validate my schema using [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup):

```
import * as yup from "yup";

let schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().min(5)
});

const x = { name: "" };

// check validity
schema
  .validate(x, { abortEarly: false })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log({ result });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log({ err });
  });
```

[codesandbox.io example](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-gould-bn861)

The `name` is empty in `x` object, But yup throw an error of `min`. Why? Which rule can be applied to solve this problem?

I need to validate for `min` **only if** I have any characters in `x`. How can I do so using yup functions?

Comment: code is working correctly in sandbox. it gives error as name don't have 5 characters

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, Lital?

Answer (score 1):

Yup throws `Error` as exception. You cant see by `console.log`. If you want to see error msg on console. In your case you want to check only if there is some value of name. Otherwise do not check run valudator for that you need to use `yup.lazy` then add condition in it:

```
const mySchema = yup.lazy((value) =>
  yup.object().shape({
    name: value.name.length > 0 && yup.string().min(5) //add condition here
  })
);
```

Here is code:

```
import * as yup from "yup";

const mySchema = yup.lazy((value) =>
  yup.object().shape({
    name: value.name.length > 0 && yup.string().min(5)
  })
);

const x = { name: "" };

// check validity
mySchema
  .validate(x, { abortEarly: false })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log({ result });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    console.log("Error message", err.message);
  });
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-render-only-input-tyjyu

Comment: no. I mean I have validation on `min` of 5. but I pass empty string in the `x.name` and I get an error of `min` although the value is not required. I want to do only when the value is not empty string when activate the `min` validator. read my question again please.

Answer (score 0):

I have a [ticket out with the makers of yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1267) to see if there is a way to do this with the built-in functionality. As a workaround, you can use a regular expression to accomplish this with the `match` function.

```
let schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().matches(/^(|.{5,})$/, "X must be at least 5 characters")
});
```

Here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-lewin-z77pc